# If I buy a game on Xbox digitally, can other users play that game?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm thinking of starting to buy Xbox games digitally, since I love how Steam works on PC, and would love similar functionality on my console. I Just have one question: If I where t buy Assassin's Creed III (or any game) on Xbox digitally, would another Xbox user on the same console be able to play that game? My brother uses the same console as me, and in the past we've always just shared disc copies of games. It'd be ridiculous if we had to buy two copies of a game digitally to both be able to play it.

Comment: As an FYI, I don't think Assassin's Creed 3 is available as a download on Xbox 360 yet. Usually games become available digitally on Xbox many months after their initial release.

Comment: Interesting, but I was just throwing out an example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The DRM for games on demand is the same as for all digital content available on Xbox LIVE:

- Any GamerTag can use the content on the console where the content was purchased
- Your GamerTag can use the content on any console, as long as that console is connected to Xbox LIVE.

See [Xbox 360 Digital Rights Management](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/marketplace-and-purchasing/download-content) for more information.

Comment: So in other words, I couldn't allow another gamertag on the same console to play the game?

Comment: @Rev - no, you absolutely could.  I use content purchased on other accounts all the time.